# Can I select the same feat twice for Critical Mastery?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, critical-hit

The Core Rulebook provides the following benefit for [Critical Mastery](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/critical-mastery-combat):

> **Benefit:** When you score a critical hit, you can apply the effects of two critical feats in addition to the damage dealt.

What I am wondering is if I can select the same feat twice. For example, can I apply Bleeding Critical twice, or Stunning Critical twice in order to make sure the target is stunned?

Since it doesn't say "You can apply two *different* critical feats" I feel it is open to interpretation, or am I reading too much into it?

Answer (score 15):

I would say the answer is no, you can't apply the same feat twice. I don't have a *strictly* RAW basis for this, but these are my reasons:

**Wording**

If the wording was "You can apply two effects of a critical feat", then the answer would be yes - the thing that is doubled is the effect, and that can be the effect of any critical feat. But here the text reads "The effects of *two critical feats*. Not the effect of *a* feat, doubled, but the effect of *two* feats.

**Prerequisites**

These are the prerequisites for Critical Mastery. I highlighted the middle one:

> Prerequisites: Critical Focus, **any two critical feats,** 14th-level fighter

Requiring two different critical feats to qualify for this feat *strongly* suggests that the intent of the rules was for two different effects to be applied, not the same one repeated.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that **you can, but be mindful of the stacking rules**. The examples you cite don't do what you seem think they would.

For example, bleed effects from the same kind of damage do not stack; that's in the definition of bleeding. So **unless you can somehow make both applications of the feat deal different kinds of damage, applying Bleeding Critical twice will not get you 4d6 bleed**. Only the first roll would even apply, because by the time the second application hits, the opponent is already bleeding from the same kind of damage.

Your other example is a little stranger, but the rules for that feat are still explicit on how stacking works. **The target doesn't have to make the save twice: instead, the second hit adds to the duration of the first**. So the effect won't "make sure the opponent is stunned", though it would at least keep the opponent stunned (or staggered) for a longer time.

Comment: Bleeding Critical is stackable, The last sentence in the Benefit description states "The effects of this feat stack."

As for Stunning Critical it says the effects of this feat do not stack but additional hits instead add duration. The reason I would want to use this feat twice is there is a fortitude check of DC10+My BAB, if beaten they become staggered instead of stunned for 1d4 rounds